# Do we need to declare variables inside class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Im new with Objective C and also new in programing.
I'm reading a book called "Objective C for Absolute Beginner" and I get problem when I try to practice with their example.

In the example, we have some method to define and they have to use some variable.
But there is no line to declare those variable and I got errors in my Xcode.
Then I try to declare those variable inside implement and it worked. (No errors any more)

My question is, this book is missing about declaring variable or it's not necessary? Or it depend on Xcode version? 
Cause in the next example I continue to get this kind of problem again.

I know this can be a silly question but I'm totally new ^^.

Thank you so much.

```
#import "RadioStation.h"

@implementation RadioStation

+ (double)minAMFrequency {
return 520.0;
}

+ (double)maxAMFrequency {
return 1610.0;
}

+ (double)minFMFrequency {
return 88.3;
}

+ (double)maxFMFrequency {
return 107.9;
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)newName atFrequency:(double)newFrequency {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
         name = newName;
         frequency = newFrequency;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)name {
    return name;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName {
     name = newName;
}

- (double)frequency {
     return frequency;
}

- (void)setFrequency:(double)newFrequency {
     frequency = newFrequency;
}
@end
```

Comment: i did not get your question? are you asking for no-synthesize or declaring a method in .m instead of .h?

Comment: is this the code thats giving you trouble? if so, you must declare "name" and "frequency" somewhere in your code, preferrably in RadioStation.h. if this does not answer your question, please elaborate...

Comment: Yes, I need to declare name and frequency to solve this problem.
But I wonder it's mistake of book's author or it's because the different of Xcode version.
Thank you all guys, I think it's mistake of book's author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your codes it seems you have four class methods, and two setters/ getters for each *name*(NSString) and *frequency*(double).

I suppose these two are propertied of your `RadioStation` class.

```
@interface RadioStation : NSObject
@property (assign) NSString *name;
@property double frequency;
@end
```

or it may be ivars as :

```
@interface RadioStation : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    double frequency;
}
@property (assign) NSString *name;
@property double frequency;
@end
```

Or, old style combination of both ivars and properties

```
@interface RadioStation : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    double frequency;
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes, Actually I fixed my problem by adding those code in my file like  you said. So my question is this issue happen because the different of Xcode version or mistake of book's author. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables in the .h or .m file as follows:

```
@interface MyViewController (){
    NSString *string;
    int integer;
}
```

Use this code at the top of your file below the imports.